# Fourier transform with compact support

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have the following problem: I have a function $f(x,t)$ with support on a compact region (red region figure). I am interested in what terms $ \widehat{\delta f} $ do I need to add to the Fourier transform $\widehat{f}$ such that the inverse Fourier transform of ${\widehat{f}+\widehat{\delta f}}$ has compact support on a sub region (blue region figure).

[Example regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vCVg.png)

I would like to know what conditions do I need to require on $f$ such that this is possible. Are there any theorems related to this question? I know the [Paley-Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem) but this is kind of the inverse problem. Any directions to the solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how it is related to Paley-Wiener. What is supposed to be $\delta$ exactly ? And did you mean $\widehat{\delta f}$ or $\delta \widehat{ f}$ ?

Comment: $(\hat{f}+\widehat{\delta f})^{\vee} = f+ \delta f$

Comment: $(\hat{f})^{\vee}=f$

Comment: The relation to the Paley Wiener theorem is the following: I started with a function $f(x,t)$ having support everywhere. For non relevant reasons I am allowed to add arbitrary Fourier modes without changing the physical state of the function. The goal is to add Fourier modes to $\hat{f}$ in such a way that the resulting (physically the same) function becomes localized in a certain region. The Paley-Wiener theorem tells what conditions this function must obey such that the Fourier transform has compact support.

With $\widehat{\delta f}$ I mean the Fourier modes I add.